# Moving Symfony vendors folder outside project means PHPStorm can't autocomplete

Tags: symfony, vagrant, composer-php

I have been using Vagrant on my Windows host using a Ubuntu VM to run a Symfony 3 app I am designing, however I got the standard problem where it was running very slowly. I performed all the tasks that are recommended:

- http://by-examples.net/2014/12/09/symfony2-on-vagrant.html
- http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html

The one where you move the vendor folder composer creates outside the project using

```
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "vendor-dir": "/home/vagrant/symfony2app/vendor"
},
```

speed up the application enormously, however by doing this PHPStorm (my IDE) could not see the folder on my Windows host and therefore lost all the autocompletes and references making development much harder!

Does anyone know a way of keeping the vendor folder outside the application, but keeping the autocompletion features?

Comment: You could add the vendor directory to "External libraries" for the project.

Comment: How do I do this though as the vendor directory is on the VM, not the windows box I am running PHPStorm on?

Comment: You could keep another copy of vendors in your windows box and add that folder to PhpStorm.

Comment: When I add to my composer.json though, or update it with latest versions of the packages, how would I sync them?